# Using grep for listing certain lines from a file

Tags: grep, vim

Using a random file, such as  `/usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor`, is there a way to list all lines that start with a 5 letter word ? How about the lines that end with a 5 letter word ? I've been thinking about this for a while now, but I didn't get anywhere yet . Does anyone know a solution ? (I'm not sure if it's doable, it's just a thought experiment )

Comment: Original question was posted on superuser.com, but was deleted due to lack of interest from the community and posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '(^[[:alpha:]]{5}[^[:alpha:]]|[^[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]{5}$)' /usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor
```

`grep -E` uses egrep

`'(a|b)'` searches for pattern `a` **or** pattern `b`

`^` is beginning-of-line, `$` is end-of-line

`[[:alpha:]]{5}` means 5 consecutive letters

`[^[:alpha:]]` means not-a-letter

So we are using egrep to look for:

- beginning of line, 5 letters, then a non-letter; *or*
- non-letter, 5 letters, then end of line

Comment: Use `-w`. The expression should be considerably simplified.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little exactly what you mean by *a word*, but something like

```
grep -E '^[[:alnum:]]{5}\b'
```

(five **alphanumeric** characters followed by a word-boundary, anchored to the start of the line) or, if your version of grep supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)

```
grep -P '^\w{5}\b'
```

(five **word characters** followed by a word-boundary, anchored to the start of the line). For the end-of-line, the equivalents would be something like

```
grep -E '\b[[:alnum:]]{5}$' file
```

or

```
grep -P '\b\w{5}$'
```

Note that for the particular file you mention, most of the lines start with leading whitespace: if you wish to ignore that, then you would need to do something like `grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]{5}\b'` or its PCRE equivalent `grep -P '^\s*\w{5}\b'`.